# How can I draw Pixmap to Qgraphicsview?

Tags: python, numpy, pyqt, qgraphicsview, qpixmap

I am trying to write code that changes some images when the scroll moves. I have used Qt Designer to draw two buttons, a scrollbar and a QGraphicsView.

I tried many ways to draw the image which is a QPixmap. It is not the problem erasing the QGraphicsView, but I want to draw this pixmap.

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4 import uic
from PyQt4.QtGui import QImage
import qimage2ndarray

import matplotlib
from matplotlib import colors as C
from matplotlib import pyplot, cm
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import dicom
import numpy
import ReadDicom as RD
import Matrixhandler as MH

form_class = uic.loadUiType('Dicom_GUI.ui')[0]

class Mainwindow(QMainWindow, form_class):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() 
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.connect(self.CTREAD, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.ct_clicked)
        self.connect(self.STRUCTREAD, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.st_clicked)
        self.CTSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.valchange)

    def ct_clicked(self):
        self.dcmList = []
        self.CTList = []
        self.dcmList = RD.dcmRead()
        RD.dSave(self.dcmList)
        self.dcmList = RD.dcmReadAll()
        self.CTList = RD.readCTdcm(self.dcmList)
        dsCT1 = dicom.read_file(self.CTList[0])
        self.x, self.y, self.z, self.dx, self.dy, self.dz, self.ConstPixelDims, self.ConstdoseDims, self.ConstdoseDimsalt, self.ConstPixelSpacing, self.ConstDoseSpacing = MH.GetCoordi(self.CTList)
        self.ArrayCT = numpy.zeros(self.ConstPixelDims, float)
        self.ArrayCT = MH.GetCTImg(self.CTList, self.ArrayCT)
        self.CTSlider.setMinimum(0)
        self.CTSlider.setMaximum(len(self.CTList)-1)

    def st_clicked(self):
        print('st clicked')

    def valchange(self):
        self.vals = self.CTSlider.value()
        self.Temparray = self.ArrayCT[:,:,self.vals]
        self.imgsh = qimage2ndarray.gray2qimage(self.Temparray)
        self.pixemap = QPixmap.fromImage(self.imgsh)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myWindow = Mainwindow()
    myWindow.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a QGraphicsPixmapItem and adding it to the graphics scene?

Comment: I just solve the problem by myself. The problem was that I was drawing to a new QGraphicsView instead of the one I already created. But however thank you everyone.